# mdDialog binding transforms object into a [object Object]

Tags: angularjs

I have a function that calls a mdDialog:

```
public deleteMediaAction(mediaItem: MediaModel): void {
    const templateType = this.mediaIsDeletable && !this.mediaIsDeleted ? 'delete-media' : 'show-deleted-media-information'
    const template = `<${templateType}
        media-item="${mediaItem}"
        on-delete="vm.deleteMedia()"
        ></${templateType}>`;

    this.$mdDialog
        .show({
            template,
            targetEvent: null,
            clickOutsideToClose: false
        })
        .then(() => {
            this.deleteMedia();
        });
    console.log(mediaItem);
}
```

The console.log here shows there correct object:

> blobId: "c06c1430-0b02-ea11-8113-00155d168404"
>
> fileName: "zav + deleted info.msg"
>
> extension: ".msg"
>
> size: 9
>
> id: "48501ff7-1602-ea11-8113-00155d168404"

Then in the `<delete-media>` component:

```
@Component('Project', {
    selector: 'delete-media',
    templateUrl: '/AttachmentListComponent/deleteMedia.html',
    bindings: {
        mediaItem: '@',
    }
})

    private mediaItem: MediaModel;

    $onInit() {
        console.log(this.mediaItem);
    }
```

The $onInit logs a

> [object object]

What's going on? Why is the `mediaItem` object being transformed into something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the template like so:

```
const template = `<${templateType}
    ̶m̶e̶d̶i̶a̶-̶i̶t̶e̶m̶=̶"̶$̶{̶m̶e̶d̶i̶a̶I̶t̶e̶m̶}̶"̶
    media-item="${JSON.stringify(mediaItem)}"
    on-delete="vm.deleteMedia()"
    ></${templateType}>`;
```

And then use one-way binding to evaluate:

```
@Component('Project', {
    selector: 'delete-media',
    templateUrl: '/AttachmentListComponent/deleteMedia.html',
    bindings: {
        ̶m̶e̶d̶i̶a̶I̶t̶e̶m̶:̶ ̶'̶@̶'̶,̶
        mediaItem: '<',
    }


})
```

Comment: Getting a `[$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: {`. Think there's something wrong with encapsulation of `media-item="${JSON.stringify(mediaItem)}"`